# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, django, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to use Black to format my Django code. It works fine in most directories. However, I get the Unicode decode error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte on the .py files in one directory in particular. The files are in UTF-8, but I have tried multiple different other encodings and have tried deleting and recreating files which hasn't resolved the issue. I'm working in an Anaconda environment, but deactivating that doesn't make any difference. I've also disabled most of my VS Code extensions.

I have looked at many SO postings on this, but none of the suggestions thus far have helped. I'm using VS Code on a Mac and have a feeling it is something to do with the fact that in the past I have edited the same code on a Windows machine using VS Code with WSL (code synced with a GitHub repo), but can't figure out how to address it. I've put a sample Traceback call below. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: If I cut and paste any of the files into another directory, then Black works fine and I don't get any encoding error messages. Which suggests there may be a directory-level issue at play?

```
(base) ➜  healthtic git:(master) ✗ black pages/views.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/bin/black", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(patched_main())
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 1130, in patched_main
    main()
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 411, in main
    sources = get_sources(
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black/__init__.py", line 477, in get_sources
    gitignore = get_gitignore(root)
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/black/files.py", line 123, in get_gitignore
    lines = gf.readlines()
  File "/Users/jh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Further edit: As mentioned above if I move files out of this directory, Black works fine, if I move them back (without any changes), the 0xFF unicode error recurs. I have attached my directory structure below, as it may be relevant that I have webpack and node modules in there for some of the frontend. My impression is that maybe a BOM may be being added somehow in the directory?

```
├── Dockerfile
├── accounts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── appointments
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── cloud_sql_proxy
├── cloudmigrate.yaml
├── config
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── basesettings.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── db.sqlite3
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── front-end
│   ├── App\ copy.js
│   ├── App.js
│   ├── index\ copy.js
│   └── index.js
├── logfile
├── manage.py
├── node_modules
│   ├── @babel
│   ├── @discoveryjs
│   ├── @types
│   ├── @webassemblyjs
│   ├── @webpack-cli
│   ├── @xtuc
│   ├── acorn
│   ├── ajv
│   ├── ajv-keywords
│   ├── ansi-styles
│   ├── babel-loader
│   ├── babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node
│   ├── babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs2
│   ├── babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3
│   ├── babel-plugin-polyfill-regenerator
│   ├── big.js
│   ├── browserslist
│   ├── buffer-from
│   ├── call-bind
│   ├── caniuse-lite
│   ├── chalk
│   ├── chrome-trace-event
│   ├── clone-deep
│   ├── color-convert
│   ├── color-name
│   ├── colorette
│   ├── commander
│   ├── commondir
│   ├── convert-source-map
│   ├── core-js-compat
│   ├── cross-spawn
│   ├── debug
│   ├── define-properties
│   ├── electron-to-chromium
│   ├── emojis-list
│   ├── enhanced-resolve
│   ├── envinfo
│   ├── es-module-lexer
│   ├── escalade
│   ├── escape-string-regexp
│   ├── eslint-scope
│   ├── esrecurse
│   ├── estraverse
│   ├── esutils
│   ├── events
│   ├── execa
│   ├── fast-deep-equal
│   ├── fast-json-stable-stringify
│   ├── fastest-levenshtein
│   ├── find-cache-dir
│   ├── find-up
│   ├── function-bind
│   ├── gensync
│   ├── get-intrinsic
│   ├── get-stream
│   ├── glob-to-regexp
│   ├── globals
│   ├── graceful-fs
│   ├── has
│   ├── has-flag
│   ├── has-symbols
│   ├── human-signals
│   ├── import-local
│   ├── interpret
│   ├── is-core-module
│   ├── is-plain-object
│   ├── is-stream
│   ├── isexe
│   ├── isobject
│   ├── jest-worker
│   ├── js-tokens
│   ├── jsesc
│   ├── json-parse-better-errors
│   ├── json-schema-traverse
│   ├── json5
│   ├── kind-of
│   ├── loader-runner
│   ├── loader-utils
│   ├── locate-path
│   ├── lodash
│   ├── lodash.debounce
│   ├── loose-envify
│   ├── make-dir
│   ├── merge-stream
│   ├── mime-db
│   ├── mime-types
│   ├── mimic-fn
│   ├── minimist
│   ├── ms
│   ├── neo-async
│   ├── node-releases
│   ├── npm-run-path
│   ├── object-assign
│   ├── object-keys
│   ├── object.assign
│   ├── onetime
│   ├── p-limit
│   ├── p-locate
│   ├── p-try
│   ├── path-exists
│   ├── path-key
│   ├── path-parse
│   ├── pkg-dir
│   ├── punycode
│   ├── randombytes
│   ├── react
│   ├── react-dom
│   ├── rechoir
│   ├── regenerate
│   ├── regenerate-unicode-properties
│   ├── regenerator-runtime
│   ├── regenerator-transform
│   ├── regexpu-core
│   ├── regjsgen
│   ├── regjsparser
│   ├── resolve
│   ├── resolve-cwd
│   ├── resolve-from
│   ├── safe-buffer
│   ├── scheduler
│   ├── schema-utils
│   ├── semver
│   ├── serialize-javascript
│   ├── shallow-clone
│   ├── shebang-command
│   ├── shebang-regex
│   ├── signal-exit
│   ├── source-list-map
│   ├── source-map
│   ├── source-map-support
│   ├── strip-final-newline
│   ├── supports-color
│   ├── tapable
│   ├── terser
│   ├── terser-webpack-plugin
│   ├── to-fast-properties
│   ├── unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript
│   ├── unicode-match-property-ecmascript
│   ├── unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript
│   ├── unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript
│   ├── uri-js
│   ├── v8-compile-cache
│   ├── watchpack
│   ├── webpack
│   ├── webpack-cli
│   ├── webpack-merge
│   ├── webpack-sources
│   ├── which
│   ├── wildcard
│   └── yocto-queue
├── notes.md
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── pages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── patient
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── patientinfo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── readme.md
├── requirements.txt
├── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── images
│   ├── index-bundle.js
│   ├── index-bundle.js.LICENSE.txt
│   └── js-bundle.js
├── staticfiles
│   ├── admin
│   ├── css
│   └── images
├── templates
│   ├── _base.html
│   ├── account
│   ├── appointments
│   ├── frontend.html
│   ├── hello_webpack.html
│   ├── home.html
│   ├── patient
│   └── patientinfo
├── todos.md
└── webpack.config.js
```

Comment: Looks like `pages/views.py` is not encoded as utf-8. `0xff` in position 0 suggests it's been encoded with utf-16 (utf-16 is sometimes used as the "unicode" encoding on Windows).

Comment: Thanks Snakecharmer. I thought I'd better triple-check before responding. At the bottom of VS Code, it tells me it's utf-8 (it could have been utf-16 in the past I guess). I've also just checked with chardet and it tells me it's ascii. However, I have checked other files where Black is working, and they also say UTF-8 and chardet also says they're ascii.

Comment: `ff` is an illegal byte in UTF-8 encoding, so it definitely is *not* UTF-8, but `ff` as the first byte is common for UTF-16 (little-endian byte order mark).  Without a dump of the first bytes of the file we otherwise can't help.  Try `open(file,'rb').read(20)` and post the bytes read.

Comment: In addition to Mark, if there is a byte `ff` in position 0, no tools will tell you that the file is UTF-8. Check that you are using the same source.  Note: what you get with a `git chackout` doesn't mean it will have same encoding on other machines (it is common to have transcoding and end-of-line convention change when working on different environments and one of them includes Windows or legacy code).

Comment: Thanks Mark and Giacomo. I've put a further edit above. The first bytes for the urls.py file (for example) is b'from django.urls imp' (it's the same if I move it out of the directory). I'm at a loss to explain the behaviour that only occurs within this directory. If I move a file out, there's no error, if I put the same file back in the directory unchanged, the error recurs. I had thought that the 0xFF related to a BOM (although VS Code tells me it is just utf-8, not utf-8-bom). Thanks for considering this.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it was my .gitignore file that was encoded in UTF-16 that was the problem. This seemed to stop Black from working in the whole directory. When I moved all of my files to another directory, I only moved the visible files (so not .gitignore), hence the unusual behaviour. Changing the .gitignore to UTF-8 solved the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue, this has fixed it.

Answer (score -3):

I don't even know what django is, but I had the same problem in a non-django program.
In that code fragment was the problem that now is fixed:

```
open(document.txt, mode= "r", encoding="utf8")
```

As you can see, the encoding it's utf8, without the "-". I used that code to open documents and read it. I hope it'll be useful!

Comment: If you look at the codec documentation, you'll find that `utf8` and `utf-8` are synonyms for the same encoding.

Comment: Thanks very much, Doppler. I'm afraid that doesn't work in my scenario.

Comment: How do you not know what Django is???

Comment: I do know what django is, but I don't like using it. (Yeah, I know it's been a year, sorry)